# Are Miles & More award miles due for Y class travel?

Tags: miles-and-more

I have flown Turkish Airlines Istanbul-Kuala Lumpur and Singapore-Istanbul.
I asked for Miles & More mileage and the Singapore-Istanbul flight is excluded from mileage awards, since I have booked in Economy class `Y`. Couldn't find any proof of that on the website.

Are Miles & More award miles due for Y class travel?

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the airline, not all flight are eligible for earning miles. Sometimes very discounted fares will earn either a reduced number of miles, or possibly none at all.

The Miles & More website has a page for each of their partner airlines that lists which fare classes are eligible for earning miles, and at what rate.

According to [their page for Turkish Airlines](http://www.miles-and-more.com/online/portal/mam/de/earn/flight/offer?nodeid=2511246&l=en&cid=18002) :

> It is not possible to earn miles in booking classes G, P, W, Z (and
>   worldwide V).

All other fares appear to earn somewhere between 0.5 and 2.0 times the number of miles flown, so I presume that you were on one of the fares listed above.

Note that "Y" frequently refers to two different things - it is normally a fare code for a full priced economy ticket,  but it's also often used to refer to any economy ticket. Thus whilst you do have an "Economy Class" ticket, you likely don't have a "Y" class ticket.

You may still be able to get credit for those flights on a different airline. eg, sometimes even if Miles & More doesn't allow credit, either the operating carrier themselves (ie, Turkish) or another partner airline like United might allow collection of miles for those fare classes - just be sure to check their first!

Comment: I think there's a good chance that either a) Giuseppe doesn't have a real "Y" class ticket, or b) The airline has made a mistake. Giuseppe, I would double check your ticket (see here for details: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4772/miles-more-what-is-a-booking-class?rq=1).

Answer (score 6):

[miles-and-more.com](http://www.miles-and-more.com/) has an online form "Mileage request" to add a flight to your mileage account, if this hasn't happened automatically.

I would just try to add the flight with this form, if that's not possible probably your used booking class is excluded from earning miles.